# How do I fix this ugly bevel?

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers

I'm making a coffee cup. My coffee cup base is a modified cylinder, and I'm trying to get rid of the sharp edges around the rim of the cup.

I tried to use the Bevel tool (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>), but that got me these ugly faces instead of the smooth, rounded edge I wanted.

[image: ugly]

I want the edge of the cup to be smooth, like a real coffee cup. Is there a tool or modifier to do this? (I already tried the Bevel modifier, and it does not bevel enough)

Comment: It depends on topology of the cup. Could you include screenshot with this cup in Edit mode ? Probably you'd like to add a loopcut to that top ring, aside from editing topology so to get smooth edges

Answer (score 2):

Just use a cube and scale it up to the size of the cup on the Y and X axis. Make sure the cube intersects the cup from above just till you can't see the bevels anymore. Select the cup, add a boolean modifier, set it to "difference" and for "object", use the cube that you have made. Apply the modifier, delete the cube and your bevels are gone! You will maybe have some lag while using smooth shading...